# Network Steganography StegoSip Tool

Tags: udp, sip, rtp, steganography

I am trying to use StegoSip tool coupled with Ekiga softphone. Finally Ekiga works, but when I run StegoSip, it gives me the warning that cb() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given).

I found the function in the code and my opinion is that stegoSip does not recognize my conversation ( third argument ). I check the port and everything looks ok (SIP uses 5060 port).

I understand that the question is details, but I wasted too much time trying to fix this and I am desperate.

StegoSIP https://github.com/epinna/Stegosip

The problematic code:

```
   def cb(self,i,nf_payload):
    """
    Callback function of packet processing.

    Get corresponding dissector and direction of packets with .getLoadedDissectorByMarker()
    and send to the correct dissector using checkPkt() and processPkt().

    """

    data = nf_payload.get_data()
    pkt = stegoIP(data)

    marker = nf_payload.get_nfmark()

    dissector, incoming = dissector_dict.dissd.getLoadedDissectorByMarker(marker)
    pkt.incoming = incoming

    if not dissector:
        nf_payload.set_verdict(nfqueue.NF_ACCEPT)
    else:
        dissector.checkPkt(pkt)
        if pkt.extracted_payload:
            dissector.processPkt(pkt, nf_payload)

    return 1
```

The output is:
         TypeError: cb() takes exactly 3 parameters (2 given)
         Callback failure!

Comment: Can you show your code and provide more details?

Comment: Note sure what this has to do with udp, rtp, etc. You aren't calling a function correctly. Automotive repair has as much to do with this question as networking. Most likely, you've only explicitly passed one argument to wherever cb is called and self gets passed implicitly. That's 2/3 of the arguments cb requires. However, I don't have a crystal ball to help, I'm sorry to say. We'll need to see cb's caller, a stack trace, or _something_ more than this.

Comment: voIP uses UDP, Ekiga uses RTP, etc. The argument which is "missing" may be the consequence of these network protocols.

Comment: It could also be because you've neglected to fill your power steering fluid in your car...which means one less sale of fluid, which means a few bytes different in somebody's inventory system somewhere... and since we're all connected via the internet, your lack of power steering fluid is causing this problem... Hope you don't mind the sarcasm too much. What you're suggesting does not follow. Your program has told you exactly what the error is. So fire up a debugger and examine the call chain and figure this bad boy out :)